# PHPUnit: force display of asserted values

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

When in PHPUnit test fails, actual and expected values are displayed.
But when the test passes, this information is not displayed.

How to force PHPUnit to always display expected and actual assertion result?

Comment: This is an unusual request. Most people would not want to do this. For this reason, nothing like this would be implemented by PHPUnit. You'd have to do it yourself.

Comment: Unrelated question, but why do you need that ? "normally", you are not supposed to produce output during tests, because there purpose is to be automatically executed (a human is not supposed to read the output if everything went good)

Comment: *Sometimes* it would be good to output something, instead of 'nothing', to show actual values. 'Can't you see? It works!', 'I don't see' anything…'.

Comment: then "echo" and "var_dump" are you friends no ? (well maybe you want to display *all* the assertions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're most likely calling the assertions with **$this->assert...()**, you can just overwrite those methods in your test case. Quick example:

```
class YourTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    ...
    static private $messages = array();
    ...
    static public function assertSame($var1, $var2, $message = '') {
        parent::assertSame($var1, $var2, $message);
        // assertSame() throws an exception if not true, so the following
        // won't occur unless the messages actually are the same
        $success = print_r($var1, true) . ' is the same as '
                 . print_r($var2, true);
        self::$messages = array_merge(self::$messages, array($success));
    }

    static public function tearDownAfterClass() {
        echo implode("\n", self::$messages);
    }
}
```

Of course, **tearDownAfterClass()** may not be late enough for your liking. It's not the same as an assertion failure would be.

Comment: Yes, I have thought about this too, but I haven't found any base method for all the assertions.

Comment: Oh! I see. But I do wonder: Would (if it existed) that be sensible? Different assertions have different semantics and different parameters. Wouldn't trying to boil them all down to one method not dilute (or worse) the effectiveness of the feedback you want?

Comment: The only sensible option for what I want is a command line switch. And an implementation if this would be a little more hassle.

Answer (score 17):

running

```
phpunit --testdox
```

will show each test name. So as a workaround, you could maybe incorporate your expected and actual assertion results inside the test name ... still it's just a workaround ...

Answer (score 3):

I came to this post looking for something similar.
I have this testcase:

```
/**
 * test routing logic (numbers method returns an array of numbers and expected outputs to test)
 * @dataProvider numbers
 */
function testRoute($input,$expected)
{
   $route = new Route($input,'',false);
   $route->route();
   $this->assertEquals($expected,$route->routingResult);
}
```

and my numbers method is this:

```
/**
 * read pairs of numbers (input <tab> expected) from tests.input separater by tab
 * return an array like this: array(array(number1,expected1), array(number2,expected2), ...)
 * provide this array to my tests by returning it
 */
function numbers()
{
    $testcases = file('tests.input');
    $tests = array();
    foreach($testcases as $test_case)
    {
        list($input,$output) = explode("\t",$test_case,2);
        $tests[] = array(trim($input),trim($output));
    }
    return $tests;
}
```

What happens is you get an output like this from phpunit:

```
 Starting test 'RouteTest::testRoute with data set #0 ('8596000000', 'rejected (dp not found)x')'.
 F
 Starting test 'RouteTest::testRoute with data set #1 ('8596000001', 'rejected (rejected by scheme)')'.
 .
 Starting test 'RouteTest::testRoute with data set #2 ('8596000003', '1599000003')'.
 .
```

It won't tell you the actual result of the tested function unless the test fails but at least you get to see all the asserted values.

Answer (score 2):

Either [create your own Assertion class](http://raphaelstolt.blogspot.com/2008/07/creating-custom-phpunit-assertions.html) and have it behave like a proxy to the actual assertion class and echoing the values before delegating to the actual assertion, e.g.

```
$this->assertWithLogging('assertion', $expected, $actual, $message);
```

or override PHPUnit's own class (which I think will be very tricky) or simply do

```
$this->assertSame($expected, $actual, $message);
echo "$expected is $actual";
```

That's not pretty either, because it will screw up output when running through CLI. If you happen to use Zend Studio, you will see the output in the Debug Output Tab.

Another route would be with [TestListeners](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener), but I don't know enough about them to tell you any details. Looks like you can hook into the testing process.

Comment: To accomplish this, I may just modify `PHPUnit_Assert`, but
I was hoping for some command line switch to have this feature on demand…

Comment: @takehin modifying core libraries is **always** a bad idea. The next time you update PHPUnit, all your mods are gone. That's why I suggested extending or using a custom assertion instead.

Comment: You're right Gordon. But that's just a hypothetical idea. I do not intend to rewrite PHPUnit nor put var_dumps everywhere, just when I want to see debug for a moment :)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just use the $message value in the assert??? method and put what ever you want in that field.  I normally use it to show what the expected and actual values are as well as a unique name for the assertion (assuming that I have more than one in a given test).

Answer (score 0):

Another thing might be to write your own Listener. This way, you can give the output you want and leave the assertions to the phpunit. This might be the easiest and most customizable way to do it I guess.